# WP 3.3 makes it possible to add meta box to Category Editor Screen?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that appears on the post and page editor screen and parses the editor content and reports back some info to the user.

I need this same plugin to appear on the category editor screen and report against the "Description" field.

Any ideas how it can be done?

I'm hoping WP 3.3 may make it easier to implement.

Here's how I'm adding the plugin to the editor screens:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
    add_meta_box('my-plugin', __('My Plugin'), 'test', 'post', 'side', 'high');
    add_meta_box('my-plugin', __('My Plugin'), 'test', 'page', 'side', 'high'); 
}
```

I'd like to be able to add this:

```
    add_meta_box('my-plugin', __('My Plugin'), 'test', 'category_edit', 'side', 'high');
```

Comment: Offtopic comment: *sigh*.. why do people keep using `admin_menu` for adding meta boxes.. Please use the `add_meta_boxes` action for adding meta boxes.

Comment: Care to "teach a man to fish"? Why should I use add_meta_boxes instead of admin_menu?

Comment: Simply change the action you're hooking onto to `add_meta_boxes` in place of `admin_menu`(of course when hooking to a screen that supports meta boxes).. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can tell no new hooks on this screen to handle metaboxes :(
the only way i see is to use the `edit_category_form_fields` with a function that prints out the fields and save them using `edited_category`

I've posted a tutorial about this a while a go [**`WordPress Category Extra Fields`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields)